# Grep into a file on remote host and scp to local

Tags: bash, ssh, scp

I am trying to find all the datanodes in a remote host, write them into a .txt file and copy it back into my local machine.

I have used the following commands:

```
# Port forwarding to remote host and scp back to local.
ssh -f user@remoteHost -L 22222:remoteHost-1:22 -N &&
ssh -t -p 22222 user@localhost "consul members | grep data | awk '{ print $2 > /tmp/data_nodes }'" &&
scp -t -p 22222 user@localhost:/tmp/data_nodes.txt .
```

This doesn't work somehow. The data_nodes file is not getting created inside /tmp directory.
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to run a remote command and get its output, then just do

```
ssh <opts> "cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3" > /path/to/local.file
```